# htaccess returning 500 error when needs to be 404

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers, http-status-code-404

How can I make it so that my htaccess rules return a 404 when invalid urls are entered into the address bar.

The two rules that are causing this

```
RewriteRule ^submit/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ /submit?c=$1&i=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^test/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /test?c=$1&i=$2&q=$3 [L]
```

Both the rules work fine when a correct url is entered but say for example one of the last parameters is not a number, it returns a 500 error.

How can I make it so that if these rules are not matched then it'll return a 404.

To further clarify take the following url `test/cooking/9/1` is valid. So is `submit/cooking/9`.

It returns 500 with urls that dont match the rewrite such as these, 'test/cooking/9/1/1`,`submit/0/0/0`, I would like it to return a 404 if the rules outlined above are **NOT** matched.

**FULL .htaccess FILE**

```
# Turn on rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite submit parameters
RewriteRule ^submit/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$ /submit?c=$1&i=$2 [L]

# Internally rewrite test parameters
RewriteRule ^test/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /test?c=$1&i=$2&q=$3 [L]

# Internally rewrite .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

# Externally redirect .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Add default charset for files
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

# G-zip deflate compression
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
     SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Those two rules aren't causing the error, you've got other rules?

Comment: Yes i'll post my full file

Comment: 500 is a server error. If the server has encountered an error then it _can't_ return a 404 response. You need to fix the error, which may not be in these lines.

Comment: @MikeW, yes I understand that, but I do not know where the error is, apache is not my forte

Comment: Take a look at the [error log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlog).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because apache is reading the URI as part of the PATH INFO, and parts of `test` or `submit` is matching the `-f` check eventhough the rest of the path doesn't. Try changing the `-f` check to:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
```

instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

Comment: Thank you, this was it. Can I ask how long it has took you to become this knowledgeable with apache, I can never seem to grasp it, or remember it.

Comment: @PEPLOVE I actually learned it by answering questions on SO, I don't even use mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thank you! I'v been struggling for ages, wondering why I get a 500 error instead of a 404. It was fine on http://homepage.co.uk/invalidurl but on http://homepage.co.uk/about/invalidurl it wasn't working, this fixed it!