# getting a 500 error instead of a 404

Tags: .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

Iv looked everywhere, and pretty much tried everything. I don't fully understand .htaccess re-writes.

So maybe someone can quickly point out something that is wrong within my .htaccess?

It's for Perch CMS. Every page works but when it cant find a page I get a 500 error, instead of a 404, and I think it's something to do with a loop or something. The error works on a home page though.

http://kieranhunter.co.uk/nopage - works (404)

http://kieranhunter.co.uk/about/nopage - Doesn't work (500)

my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^detail/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /detail.php?s=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /category.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /blog/post.php?s=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/preview$ /blog/post.php?s=$1&preview=all [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /blog/archive.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /blog/archive.php?cat=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/date/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /blog/archive.php?year=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/date/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /blog/archive.php?year=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/date/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /blog/archive.php?year=$1&month=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/date/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/archive.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/tag/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /blog/archive.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/tag/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /blog/archive.php?tag=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/{0,1}$ /blog/archive.php?year=$1&month=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /blog/archive.php?year=$1&month=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 400 /404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
ErrorDocument 502 /404.php
ErrorDocument 504 /404.php

RewriteRule (.*).xml(.*) $1.php$2 [nocase]

#Old posts re-direct
Redirect 301 /my-portfolio /portfolio

Redirect 301 /welcome-to-my-portfolio-site /blog/welcome-to-my-portfolio-site 
Redirect 301 /new-canon-450d /blog/my-new-canon-450d
Redirect 301 /google-authorship-now-works /blog/how-to-make-your-google-authorship-work
Redirect 301 /my-first-codepen /blog/my-first-codepen
Redirect 301 /wordpress-theme-development /blog/developing-my-custom-wordpress-theme
Redirect 301 /my-review-on-sniper-elite-3-xbox-one /blog/my-review-on-sniper-elite-3-xbox-one
Redirect 301 /custom-project-types-for-your-portfolio /blog/custom-project-types-for-your-portfolio
Redirect 301 /custom-social-share-buttons-author-information /blog/custom-social-share-buttons-with-author-information
Redirect 301 /social-media-icons-with-hover-titles /blog/social-media-icons-with-hover-titles
Redirect 301 /creating-perfect-favicon /blog/creating-the-perfect-favicon
Redirect 301 /javascript-image-animation-frames /blog/javascript-image-animation-frames
Redirect 301 /hide-your-arms-t-shirt-blog /blog/hide-your-arms-t-shirt-blog
Redirect 301 /the-joy-of-sublime-text-2 /blog/the-joy-of-sublime-text-2
Redirect 301 /implementing-wordpress-post-formats /blog/implementing-wordpress-post-formats
Redirect 301 /using-icomoon-icons /blog/the-best-way-to-implement-font-icons
Redirect 301 /how-to-test-your-fish-water-and-resolving-nitrite-poisoning /blog/how-to-test-your-fish-water-and-resolving-nitrite-poisoning
Redirect 301 /update-on-my-aquariums-nitrite-poisoning /blog/update-on-my-aquariums-nitrite-poisoning
Redirect 301 /next-previous-wordpress-post-links /blog/next-previous-wordpress-post-links
Redirect 301 /shouldnt-using-target_blank-outbound-links /blog/why-you-shouldnt-be-using-target-blank-for-outbound-links
Redirect 301 /set-photoshop-document-brush-presets-illustrate-using-tablet /blog/how-to-set-up-your-photoshop-document-and-brush-presets-to-illustrate-using-a-tablet
Redirect 301 /migrating-wordpress-perch-cms /blog/migrating-from-wordpress-to-perch-cms
Redirect 301 /uk-plugs-logo-web-design /blog/uk-plugs-logo-web-design
Redirect 301 /pug-love-photoshop-illustration /blog/pug-love-photoshop-illustration
Redirect 301 /feather-threadless-submission /blog/feather-threadless-submission
Redirect 301 /fresh-new-theme-from-themeforest /blog/fresh-new-theme-from-themeforest
Redirect 301 /5-web-design-and-blog-trends-for-you-to-think-about-for-2014 /blog/5-web-design-and-blog-trends-for-you-to-think-about-for-2014
Redirect 301 /social-media-image-sprites /blog/social-media-image-sprites
Redirect 301 /final-fantasy-x-x-2-hd /blog/final-fantasy-xx-2-hd-review

#block libwww-perl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

#re-direct http://www. to http://
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.kieranhunter\.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/kieranhunter\.co.uk\/" [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Kieran

UPDATE: This post fixed it I think!! [htaccess returning 500 error when needs to be 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575659/htaccess-returning-500-error-when-needs-to-be-404)

Comment: What is `ErrorDocument 500 /404.php` about?

Comment: Does there happen to be a `/about.php` page?

Comment: I think it's supposed to re-redirect 500 errors to the 404.php page? But it doesn't so maybe I'll delete that block.

Comment: Yes, there's an /about.php page